# IMU data using ble protocol is in a weird format

Tags: signal-analysis

I am working on IMU data, this data was collected using wrist watch under the protocol BLE the reading are non-interpretable for me:

```
"data":"eyJBWCI6MC42OTksIkFZIjowLjY2NiwiQVoiOjAuMjIyLCJHWCI6MTYuMjk2LCJHWSI6OS44ODcsIkdaIjotMTMuODU1fQ==","from":{"Name":"wristband-d5","Protocol":"BLE"},"datetime":"2021-10-31T12:37:21.1352384-04:00","type":0
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like it's a base64 format, to convert inherently binary data into something printable that'll pass through BLE without looking like control characters.  You should start by looking to see if the structure of the binary record that's being passed is documented someplace; unless there's a known wristband format then there's a good chance that it's specific to your brand or even brand & model of watch.

Comment: convert from base64 to hexadecimal and then look at different measurements, see if you can spot patterns

Comment: The method that @user253751 gives is the way to go if you can't find data.  Given how long that string is, there's more there than three accelerations and three rotations.

Answer (score 1):

It's [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. The string

```
eyJBWCI6MC42OTksIkFZIjowLjY2NiwiQVoiOjAuMjIyLCJHWCI6MTYuMjk2LCJHWSI6OS44ODcsIkdaIjotMTMuODU1fQ==
```

decodes to

```
{"AX":0.699,"AY":0.666,"AZ":0.222,"GX":16.296,"GY":9.887,"GZ":-13.855}
```

You can [try it online here](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Comment: OK.  _Why_ use base64, which is designed to make binary printable, and use it to encode something that's _already_ printable, and human-readable to boot?